# how to using group concat distinct count in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

Now I am using MySQL 5.7, I have some data like this:

```
user_id

63763
63763
NULL
16459,16535,16613,16615,42896,42911,62463,62464,63594,63763,63764,63765,63766,63769,63930,63934,63935
NULL
NULL
```

I want to concat the user_id and distinct , finnally count the result of distinct result(finally I find the result still have duplicate value), is it possible to complete it in one sql? I known distinct like this:

```
select group_concat(DISTINCT user_id SEPARATOR ',')
from report_summary
where statistic_time >= 1615824000000
```

how to count the result?

[image]

and now I found the result still have duplicate value using this sql:

```
select group_concat(DISTINCT bet_user_ids SEPARATOR ',')
from report_summary
where statistic_time >= 1616083200000
and statistic_time <= 1616169599999
```

the result is:

```
16459,16535,16613,16615,18627,42890,42896,46521,62463,62464,63591,63595,63763,63764,63765,63769,63934,63939,63940,42890,42896,42890,42896,62463,63763
```

the user `42890` have three times in the result.

Comment: Split CSV to separate values, then concat distinct values back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this with one operator, but you can use the following *trick* to accomplish it:

```
select group_concat(DISTINCT user_id SEPARATOR ','),
    LENGTH(group_concat(DISTINCT user_id SEPARATOR ',')) - LENGTH(REPLACE(group_concat(DISTINCT user_id SEPARATOR ','), ',', '')) + 1 AS IdCount
from report_summary
where statistic_time >= 1615824000000
```

Basically it counts the number of commas (+ 1) in the list by subtracting the length of the string after removing the commas from the original string's length. I thought it was pretty nifty and found it in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7020024/5059085).